# try/catch block in calling generator function is never called

Tags: dart

Can someone please explain to me why the calling generator function try/catch block is never run?

```
/// Dart program with nested stream for showing why try/catch blocs 
/// in calling generator function is never called.
void main() async {
  try {
    await for (var val in generator()) {
      print('Value: $val');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}

Stream<int> generator() async* {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    try {
      yield* generator2();
      yield i;
    } catch (e) {
      // This catch block is never called. Never!
      print('Woot');
    }
  }
}

Stream<int> generator2() async* {
  for (int i = 100; i < 110; i++) {
    if (i == 105) {
      throw GeneratorException('Error on generating $i');
    }
    yield i;
  }
}

class GeneratorException {
  const GeneratorException(this.message);
  final String message;
}
```

You can also try the below dartpad:

https://nullsafety.dartpad.dev/437b31a747cf7bacfa2332408c98f849

Answer (score 2):

I think it is by design if you read the Dart specification:

> If `m` is marked `async*`(9), then:
>
> ...
>
> The `o` stream is listened to, creating a subscription `s`, and for each event `x`, or error `e` with stack trace `t`, of `s`:
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise, `x`, or `e` with `t`, are added to the stream associated with `m` in the order they appear in `o`. **Note that a dynamic error occurs if `x` is added and the dynamic type of `x` is not a subtype of the element type of said stream.** The function `m` may suspend.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf

So when you do `yield*` you are forwarding all events from this `Stream` including errors.